# How do you open comments for anonymous user for a specific content type (blogs) in Drupal?

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I want to open comments for anonymous users also but only for blogs content type. Is there any module I need to download or we need to do it programmatically or it can be done through the Drupal backend?

Answer (score 1):

It can done through drupal permissions, goto "people/permissions" search for comment and look for post comments settings and check the checkbox for anonymous  user.